# Calling REST index action from Dashboard

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest

Hello Everyone I have a model 'Project' in my rails application which is a REST resource.

I also have a non REST controller 'home' with a method 'dashboard'.

I want the dashboard to render all the Projects. This means, I need to call index action on Project. There are two ways I can think of for doing this:

1.

> Have a link_to to Project#Index in my dashbaord template, then as both
>   dashboard and Index share same layout, user can see list of Projects.
>   However this needs an extra click.

2.

> As all other view elements for Dashboard lie in the layout file, I
>   could manually set the @projects instance in dashboard action and
>   render the index template.

This also looks like a wrong way to approach things.

What I have two models 'Project' and say 'Cookie' and I want to list them all in my dashboard? How to go about implementing it in the neatest way possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController
  def dashboard
    @projects = Project.all
    @cookies = Cookie.all
  end
end
```

In your views/home/dashboard you represent those collections as you need.

If you have a partial in your views/projects/ directory, that is currently used within the projects index action to render the project collection, then you can use that view in your dashboard by calling something like:

```
<%= render partial: 'projects/list', locals: { projects: @projects } %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like in your ProjectController's dashboard method you should be calling something like

```
projects = Project.find_all
```

then rendering projects in your corresponding view.